# execute cshtml code on selection changed to retrieve items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a cshtml page that has some selection that I'd like to execute some other C# code to fetch items when the selection is changed.

```
var choices= new List<string[]>();
<select name="student" onselect="">
            @foreach (var student in students)
            {
                <option value="@student[0]" onselect="@{
                                                           choices = choice.ReturnChoices(@student[0]);
                                                      }">@student[2] @student[3] @student[4]</option>
            }
        </select>
```

Now, I'd like to call the method that returns the student choices when the student value changes and populate another dropdown/select.

However, currently, on loading, the dropdown is showing all the choices.

Comment: you need cascaded dropdown list, there are many articles on how to implement cascaded dropdown in mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to register onselect (JavaScript) event, and on this give an ajax call to the controller along with the student name which will return the list of the choices. and on the success of ajax call fill the second drop down using jquery/javascript and you can show the progress bar while drop down is being populating.

```
<select name="student" onselect="onStudentSelect()">

function onStudentSelect(){
    $.ajax({
                    url: //Url to your action method along with the student name in query string,
                    type:get,
                    dataType: "json",
                    complete: function() {
                        //remove progress bar.
                    },
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        //Show progress bar.
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        //fill second drop down like:
                        //$("#secondDropDown").append('<option value="' + anyvalue + '">' + anyText + '</option>');
                    }
                });   
}
```

Comment: ok, so i have to use ajax? i was avoiding ajax and all those. i wanted to stick to inline cshtml which i'm more comfortable with

Comment: since you have to implement cascading dropdown, means second drop down value depends on first selection. So this should be handled at client side. Server did not have the information about the first drop down selected value, Only client can inform server that which value is selected.  Razor code is server side code and you can not implement cascading dropdown with client side code.